# Updating okhttp to not block in coroutines actually decreases throughput

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, okhttp

I'm having a hard time troubleshooting why the following extension function based on [okhttp-coroutines](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-coroutines) ends up reducing throughput of okhttp?

For example, I get about 1/4 the concurrent requests when performing the following:

```
val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient()
List(20_000).chunked(200).map {
  async(Dispatchers.IO){
    okHttpClient.newCall(request).executeAsync()
  }
}
```

in comparison to - which ends up being 4x faster, even though `::execute` is a blocking call?

```
List(20_000).chunked(200).map {
  async(Dispatchers.IO){
    okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute()
  }
}
```

Updating the `Dispatcher`'s default max requests didn't result any changes:

```
val dispatcher =
    Dispatcher().apply {
        maxRequestsPerHost = MAX_REQUESTS
        maxRequests = MAX_REQUESTS
    }
val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
            .dispatcher(dispatcher)
            .build()
```

Comment: I think `executeAsync` does not use coroutines, but just create/use  a pool of system threads to run the request, which can only add more overhead. As you've already taken care of synchronous call parallelization with dispatchers IO, and already have chunked request, adding more threading mechanism have more chance to impact performance negatively.